# How Does the Fable 3 co-op chat work?

Tags: pc, fable-3

I've been playing some Fable 3 co-op, and I can't figure it out!

How can I chat with my co-op partner?

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://lionhead.com/forums/t/304290.aspx) might help.

The answer is essentially that you can't. You can invite them to a party (XBox) or open a chat (Games for Windows Live) or something similar. But there isn't a built-in chat client, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can! Just plug in your mic and it should work.

Comment: Can you provide more information? This seems to contradict the existing, upvoted answer, so a little more detail would be useful.